# If $f: X\to [0, 1]$ is continuous and $f(A)=0$, $f(B)=1$, then there exists a continuous $g: X\to [a, b]$ such that $g(A)=a$, $g(B)=b$ for any $a<b$.

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

**The Problem**: Suppose $X$ is normal and $A, B\subseteq X$ are closed. Suppose $f: X\to [0, 1]$ is continuous and $f(A)=0$, $f(B)=1$. Then there exists a continuous $g: X\to [a, b]$ such that $g(A)=a$, $g(B)=b$ for any $a<b$.

**Context**: The proof of *Urysohn Lemma* in James Munkres' *Topology, $\mathit{2^{rd}}$* only shows that the existence of a continuous function from $X$ to $[0, 1]$. The general case (i.e., a continuous function from $X$ to $[a, b]$) should follow quite easily; but I somehow failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take $g = h \circ f$, where $h\colon [0, 1] \to [a, b]$ is defined by $h(x) = (b - a)x + a$.

Comment: @Adriano Mind Blown. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let consider $g=h\circ f$, where $h:[0,1]\to[a,b]$ which is defined by $$h(f(x))=(b-a)f(x)+a.$$ this should rescale your codomain. And $g(A)=h(f(A)=a$, $g(B)=h(f(B)=b$ for any $a<b$.